# Сохранение данных QDoubleSpinBox из интерфейса PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qsettings, pyqt6

У меня в интерфейсе очень много окошек класса `QDoubleSpinBox`. 
Соответственно каждый раз при запуске программы данные в них обнуляются. 
Я задумал сделать кнопки сохранения и открытия файла сохранения, дабы каждый раз не вводить всё заново.

Я создал метод `save_infile(self)`, который вызывается по нажатию кнопки "сохранить" и в нём прописал функцию автоматического поиска этих самых `QDoubleSpinBox`, а именно:

`self.ui.tabs = self.ui.scrollAreaWidget_bvr.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox)`

Метод работает, однако он делает список из объектов PyQt6, который каждый раз разные. Да и сохранить их нельзя через `pickle`. А даже если я через метод `value()` проитерирую список и сохраню новый со значениями, то потом не факт что значения встанут на свои места. 
Я попробовал, действительно встают в рандомные места, вот реализация:

```
def save_infile(self):
    self.ui.tabs = self.ui.scrollAreaWidget_bvr.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox)
    self.ui.tabs_scar = []
    for i in self.ui.tabs:
        self.ui.tabs_scar.append(i.value())
    sf_data = self.ui.tabs_scar
    sf = open(r"Geo_Data.txt", "wb")
    pickle.dump(sf_data, sf)
    sf.close()
    print("Save Successes")

def open_savefile(self):
    sl = open(r"Geo_Data.txt", "rb")
    sl_data = pickle.load(sl)
    sl.close()
    self.ui.tabs = self.ui.scrollAreaWidget_bvr.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox)
    index = 0
    for i in self.ui.tabs:
        i.setValue(sl_data[index])
        index += 1
    print("Open Successes")
```

В общем мой вопрос как бы вы лучше сделали эту функцию и как сохранить данные из QDoubleSpinBox в файл чтобы потом из него же их и загрузить?

Ещё я пробовал через `objectName()` виджетов, но в таком случае когда я хочу задать новое значение, программа не понимает к какому объекту ссылаться, потому названия виджетов в словаре храняться как `string`:

```
import copy, pprint
import Question_int as interf
from PyQt6 import QtCore,QtWidgets,QtGui

import pickle

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.ui = interf.Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    #menu actions
    self.ui.actionSave.triggered.connect(self.save_infile)
    self.ui.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.open_savefile)

def save_infile(self):
    self.ui.tabs = self.ui.scrollAreaWidget_bvr.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox)
    self.ui.tabs_names = []
    self.ui.tabs_values = []
    for i in self.ui.tabs:
        self.ui.tabs_names.append(i.objectName())
    for i in self.ui.tabs:
        self.ui.tabs_values.append(i.value())

    sf_data = dict(zip(self.ui.tabs_names,self.ui.tabs_values))
    sf = open(r"TEST.txt", "wb")
    pickle.dump(sf_data, sf)
    sf.close()
    print("Save Successes")

def open_savefile(self):
    sl = open(r"TEST.txt", "rb")
    sl_data = pickle.load(sl)
    sl.close()

    self.ui.tabs_names = []
    self.ui.tabs_values = []

    self.ui.tabs_names = list(sl_data.keys())
    self.ui.tabs_values = list(sl_data.values())
    index = 0
    for i in self.ui.tabs_names:
        i.setValue(self.ui.tabs_values[index])
        index += 1

    print("Open Successes") #(нет)


if __name__== "__main__":
import sys
app = interf.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Form = MainWindow()
Form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Интерфейс для копирования:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(678, 824)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
    self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
    self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.HLine)
    self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Sunken)
    self.line.setObjectName("line")
    self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.line, 1, 0, 1, 2)
    self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.TabPosition.North)
    self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.TabShape.Rounded)
    self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
    self.tab_bvr = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.tab_bvr.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 1359))
    self.tab_bvr.setObjectName("tab_bvr")
    self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_bvr)
    self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
    self.scrollArea_bvr = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.tab_bvr)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollArea_bvr.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.scrollArea_bvr.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.scrollArea_bvr.setMouseTracking(False)
    self.scrollArea_bvr.setAccessibleDescription("")
    self.scrollArea_bvr.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.scrollArea_bvr.setObjectName("scrollArea_bvr")
    self.scrollAreaWidget_bvr = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.scrollAreaWidget_bvr.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 634, 710))
    self.scrollAreaWidget_bvr.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    self.scrollAreaWidget_bvr.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidget_bvr")
    self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidget_bvr)
    self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
    self.subtabs_bvr = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.scrollAreaWidget_bvr)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.subtabs_bvr.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.subtabs_bvr.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.subtabs_bvr.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.subtabs_bvr.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.TabPosition.North)
    self.subtabs_bvr.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.TextElideMode.ElideNone)
    self.subtabs_bvr.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
    self.subtabs_bvr.setObjectName("subtabs_bvr")
    self.tab_bvr_overall = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tab_bvr_overall.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.tab_bvr_overall.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.tab_bvr_overall.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
    self.tab_bvr_overall.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 380))
    self.tab_bvr_overall.setAcceptDrops(True)
    self.tab_bvr_overall.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.tab_bvr_overall.setObjectName("tab_bvr_overall")
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_bvr_overall)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    self.InputData_01 = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.tab_bvr_overall)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.InputData_01.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.InputData_01.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.StyleStrategy.PreferAntialias)
    self.InputData_01.setFont(font)
    self.InputData_01.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.ArrowCursor))
    self.InputData_01.setMouseTracking(False)
    self.InputData_01.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ContextMenuPolicy.DefaultContextMenu)
    self.InputData_01.setAccessibleDescription("")
    self.InputData_01.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.InputData_01.setStyleSheet("")
    self.InputData_01.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Sunken)
    self.InputData_01.setLineWidth(1)
    self.InputData_01.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
    self.InputData_01.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.InputData_01.setObjectName("InputData_01")
    self.scrollArea_overall = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.scrollArea_overall.setEnabled(True)
    self.scrollArea_overall.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 590, 360))
    self.scrollArea_overall.setObjectName("scrollArea_overall")
    self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollArea_overall)
    self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
    self.input_overall_03 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.scrollArea_overall)
    self.input_overall_03.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(75, 16777215))
    self.input_overall_03.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    self.input_overall_03.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.ButtonSymbols.NoButtons)
    self.input_overall_03.setPrefix("")
    self.input_overall_03.setSuffix("")
    self.input_overall_03.setMaximum(3000.99)
    self.input_overall_03.setObjectName("input_overall_03")
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.input_overall_03, 2, 0, 1, 1)
    self.input_overall_02 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.scrollArea_overall)
    self.input_overall_02.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(75, 16777215))
    self.input_overall_02.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    self.input_overall_02.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.ButtonSymbols.NoButtons)
    self.input_overall_02.setPrefix("")
    self.input_overall_02.setSuffix("")
    self.input_overall_02.setDecimals(0)
    self.input_overall_02.setMaximum(3001.0)
    self.input_overall_02.setProperty("value", 0.0)
    self.input_overall_02.setObjectName("input_overall_02")
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.input_overall_02, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.input_overall_01 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.scrollArea_overall)
    self.input_overall_01.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(75, 16777215))
    self.input_overall_01.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.input_overall_01.setWrapping(True)
    self.input_overall_01.setFrame(True)
    self.input_overall_01.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    self.input_overall_01.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.ButtonSymbols.NoButtons)
    self.input_overall_01.setSpecialValueText("")
    self.input_overall_01.setCorrectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.CorrectionMode.CorrectToPreviousValue)
    self.input_overall_01.setPrefix("")
    self.input_overall_01.setSuffix("")
    self.input_overall_01.setMaximum(3000.99)
    self.input_overall_01.setObjectName("input_overall_01")
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.input_overall_01, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.InputData_01.setWidget(self.scrollArea_overall)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.InputData_01, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.subtabs_bvr.addTab(self.tab_bvr_overall, "")
    self.tab_bvr_drilling = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.tab_bvr_drilling.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 280))
    self.tab_bvr_drilling.setObjectName("tab_bvr_drilling")
    self.gridLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_bvr_drilling)
    self.gridLayout_6.setObjectName("gridLayout_6")
    self.InputData_02 = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.tab_bvr_drilling)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.InputData_02.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.InputData_02.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.InputData_02.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("MS Serif")
    font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.StyleStrategy.PreferAntialias)
    self.InputData_02.setFont(font)
    self.InputData_02.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.SizeAdjustPolicy.AdjustIgnored)
    self.InputData_02.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.InputData_02.setObjectName("InputData_02")
    self.scrollArea_drilling = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.scrollArea_drilling.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 590, 260))
    self.scrollArea_drilling.setObjectName("scrollArea_drilling")
    self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollArea_drilling)
    self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
    self.input_drilling_02 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.scrollArea_drilling)
    self.input_drilling_02.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(75, 16777215))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
    self.input_drilling_02.setFont(font)
    self.input_drilling_02.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    self.input_drilling_02.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.ButtonSymbols.NoButtons)
    self.input_drilling_02.setMaximum(3000.99)
    self.input_drilling_02.setObjectName("input_drilling_02")
    self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.input_drilling_02, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.input_drilling_01 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.scrollArea_drilling)
    self.input_drilling_01.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(75, 16777215))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
    self.input_drilling_01.setFont(font)
    self.input_drilling_01.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    self.input_drilling_01.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.ButtonSymbols.NoButtons)
    self.input_drilling_01.setMaximum(3000.99)
    self.input_drilling_01.setObjectName("input_drilling_01")
    self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.input_drilling_01, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.InputData_02.setWidget(self.scrollArea_drilling)
    self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.InputData_02, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.subtabs_bvr.addTab(self.tab_bvr_drilling, "")
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.subtabs_bvr)
    self.scrollArea_bvr.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidget_bvr)
    self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.scrollArea_bvr, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_bvr, "")
    self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 2)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 678, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
    self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.actionNew = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionNew.setObjectName("actionNew")
    self.actionOpen = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
    self.actionSave = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
    self.actionSave_as = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionSave_as.setObjectName("actionSave_as")
    self.actionExit = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
    self.actionExport = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionExport.setObjectName("actionExport")
    self.actionEdit = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionEdit.setObjectName("actionEdit")
    self.actionCalculate_all = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionCalculate_all.setObjectName("actionCalculate_all")
    self.actionGlossary = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionGlossary.setObjectName("actionGlossary")
    self.actionHelp = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionHelp.setObjectName("actionHelp")
    self.actionAbout_GeoGraph = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionAbout_GeoGraph.setObjectName("actionAbout_GeoGraph")
    self.import_xlsx = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.import_xlsx.setObjectName("import_xlsx")
    self.actionCSV_File = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionCSV_File.setObjectName("actionCSV_File")
    self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
    self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave)
    self.menuFile.addSeparator()
    self.menuFile.addSeparator()
    self.menuFile.addSeparator()
    self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
    self.subtabs_bvr.setCurrentIndex(0)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Question"))
    self.subtabs_bvr.setTabText(self.subtabs_bvr.indexOf(self.tab_bvr_overall), _translate("MainWindow", "subtab1"))
    self.subtabs_bvr.setTabText(self.subtabs_bvr.indexOf(self.tab_bvr_drilling), _translate("MainWindow", "subtab2"))
    self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_bvr), _translate("MainWindow", "tab1"))
    self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
    self.actionNew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New"))
    self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
    self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
    self.actionSave_as.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save as"))
    self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
    self.actionExport.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Export..."))
    self.actionEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
    self.actionCalculate_all.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Calculate all"))
    self.actionGlossary.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Glossary"))
    self.actionHelp.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
    self.actionAbout_GeoGraph.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "About GeoGraph"))
    self.import_xlsx.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Excel File"))
    self.actionCSV_File.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CSV File"))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Основная проблема в том, что метод `objectName()` возвращает string из списка `self.ui.tabs`. Может быть есть возможность структурно записывать ссылки на объекты `QDoubleSpinBox`? Может быть есть параметры дополнительные у метода `findChildren()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я взял пример из предыдущего вашего вопроса.

> Класс QSettings обеспечивает постоянные настройки приложения,
> не зависящие от платформы.
>
> Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html

QSettings - это абстракция этих технологий, позволяющая сохранять
и восстанавливать настройки приложения переносимым способом.
Он также поддерживает настраиваемые форматы хранения.

---

```
'''
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.input_overall_1 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_overall_1.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.input_overall_1.setWrapping(True)
        self.input_overall_1.setFrame(True)
        self.input_overall_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.input_overall_1.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.ButtonSymbols.NoButtons)
        self.input_overall_1.setSpecialValueText("")
        self.input_overall_1.setCorrectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.CorrectionMode.CorrectToPreviousValue)
        self.input_overall_1.setPrefix("")
        self.input_overall_1.setSuffix("")
        self.input_overall_1.setMaximum(3000.99)
        self.input_overall_1.setObjectName("input_overall_1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.input_overall_1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.input_overall_2 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_overall_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.input_overall_2.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.ButtonSymbols.NoButtons)
        self.input_overall_2.setPrefix("")
        self.input_overall_2.setSuffix("")
        self.input_overall_2.setMaximum(3000.99)
        self.input_overall_2.setObjectName("input_overall_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.input_overall_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.input_overall_3 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_overall_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.input_overall_3.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.ButtonSymbols.NoButtons)
        self.input_overall_3.setPrefix("")
        self.input_overall_3.setSuffix("")
        self.input_overall_3.setMaximum(3000.99)
        self.input_overall_3.setObjectName("input_overall_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.input_overall_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.calc_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.calc_button.setFont(font)
        self.calc_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(213, 213, 213);")
        self.calc_button.setObjectName("calc_button")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.calc_button, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.calc_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Расчёт"))
        

CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config_q1330905.ini'    # !!! сюда будем сохранять                       
        
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.doubleSpinBoxs = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox)
        #print(f'doubleSpinBoxs = {self.doubleSpinBoxs}') 

# +++
        self.load_settings()                                       # +++
        
        for dsb in self.doubleSpinBoxs:
            dsb.valueChanged.connect(
                lambda val, dsb=dsb: self.gather_data(val, dsb))
       
        self.calc_button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)        

    def on_clicked(self):
        rez = 0
        for dsb in self.doubleSpinBoxs:
            rez += dsb.value()
        print(f"Button Pushed: rez = {rez}")

    def gather_data(self, val, dsb):
        txt = dsb.value()
        print(f'{dsb.objectName()}: {val} <----> {txt}')

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('Geometry',    self.saveGeometry())
        settings.setValue('WindowState', self.saveState())

        for doubleSpinBox in self.doubleSpinBoxs:
            obj = doubleSpinBox.objectName()
            settings.setValue(obj,  doubleSpinBox.value())
            
    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)   
        geometry = settings.value('Geometry')
        if geometry:
            self.restoreGeometry(geometry)
        state = settings.value('WindowState')
        if state:
            self.restoreState(state)

        for doubleSpinBox in self.doubleSpinBoxs:
            obj = doubleSpinBox.objectName()
            doubleSpinBox.setValue(float(settings.value(obj, 0)))
    
    def closeEvent(self, e):
        self.save_settings()
        super().closeEvent(e)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__== "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = MainWindow()
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @AddmiX вы спросили как сохранить - я вам показал вариант решения. Я не совсем понимаю о каких исходниках вы говорите и какую подобную функцию вы хотите найти в  QSettings.

Comment: да, я прошу прощения я не увидел про ini файл, а когда увидел удалил комментарий =) Ваше решение подходит

Comment: Но я всё же думаю что через `pickle` это также возможно сделать, просто это менее удобно

Comment: @AddmiX я вам показал правильное решение. Можно придумать что угодно, но оно будет так себе.

Comment: странно, но PyQt6 сообщает что `QSettings` не имеет атрибута `IniFormat`

Comment: @AddmiX  QtCore.QSettings.`Format.IniFormat`

Comment: спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @AddmiX если мои ответы учат вас чему-то новому, вы также можете отмечать мои ответы и как полезные.

Comment: Да, с удовольствием, мне только сейчас дали такую привилегию